# CRM 2011 & Typescript: How to get sections within a tab

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, typescript

We're implementing our client-side logic using TypeScript on one of our CRM 2011 projects. So far, so good.

However, something seems off in the Xrm2011.1_0.d.ts file regarding sections. Tabs and sections are defined as follows:

```
module Xrm {
    export module Page {
        ...
        export module ui {
            ...
            export module tabs {
                ...
                export function get(tabName: string): Tab;
                ...
                export module sections {
                    ...
                    export function get(sectionName: string): Section;
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This forces you to implement typescript as such:

```
var section = <Xrm.Page.Section>Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.sections.get(sectionName);
```

Which compiles to:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.sections.get(sectionName);
```

However, the correct JavaScript syntax should be:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tabName).sections.get(sectionName);
```

Has anyone experienced this? Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, both `tags.get()` and `tabs.sections` should be available, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The last syntax won't work. Tab isn't a class so tabs.get is returning a Tb class but the Tab class doesn't have a .sections property. You also shouldn't need to cast.

Ps.... Try declaring your modules with dot notation "export Xrm.Page.ui.tabs". It will make you code more readable.

Also, what made you make some classes capital case and some not?

Comment: Try read my question again, and more thouroughly, Scott. I'm not looking for a lecture on how to implement TypeScript or JavaScript. This is not my code. This is a query on the **existing** Xrm.Page definition file, which we use to implement logic based on the **existing** Xrm.Page context in CRM 2011... Thanks for the try though..